# Is there a way to decompress client's request body in nginx?

Tags: nginx, gzip

The client gzips post body, and I want the nginx decompress post body first, then passes the decompressed content to backend web server.

I can only find the way to compress response to client.

Any solution?
Thanks first!

Comment: I am not finding a module, but have you considered using a language such as lua to decompress or write it in c?

Comment: @chrislovecnm I'm trying to find an existing solution first, if none, I might implement one myself

Comment: @aehlke No, I just write one small handler by myself in Java servlet

Comment: @MartinLuo and I wrote a WSGI middleware :(